# MySQL delete statement based on sub-select with multiple return values

Tags: mysql, subquery

MySQL delete statement based on sub-select with multiple return values.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
DELETE FROM `dnsstats` WHERE id NOT IN
(

 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = 'x.x.x.243' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
    ) foo 
)
 AND id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = 'x.x.x.40' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
  ) foo2
)
 AND id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = 'x.x.x.50' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
  ) foo3
);
```

This works great, but I would like to select the individual IP addresses dynamically like so:

```
SELECT peerhost FROM `dnsstats` GROUP BY peerhost;
```

..and delete based on those returned values.

This is what i tried (and failed):

```
DELETE FROM `dnsstats` WHERE id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = (
            SELECT peerhost FROM `dnsstats` GROUP BY peerhost;
        ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
    ) foo 
);
```

Any idea what I can do to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might need to remove the semicolon in
SELECT peerhost FROM `dnsstats` GROUP BY peerhost;

The query will run but I don't think you'll get the correct result:
Earlier you were getting 500 from each id related to a peerhost,

now you'll be getting total 500 for all. You need to change the query.

==> Edit: Try this Bryan

```
DELETE FROM dnsstats WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT e.id FROM
    (
        SELECT d.id FROM dnsstats d
        LEFT JOIN
    (
            SELECT a.peerhost,
                (SELECT id FROM dnsstats WHERE peerhost = a.peerhost
                    ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 499,1) id
            FROM 
            (SELECT peerhost FROM dnsstats GROUP BY peerhost) a
    ) c
    ON d.peerhost = c.peerhost
WHERE d.id < c.id) e);
```

Comment: Plus of course replacing '=' by 'IN' as already mentioned by Jandisson

Comment: You are correct, I would like to keep 500 records per id. I should have elaborated. How can I fix this?

Comment: Check the addition to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

That is what you want?

```
DELETE FROM `dnsstats` WHERE id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost in (
            SELECT peerhost FROM `dnsstats` GROUP BY peerhost;
        ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
    ) foo 
);
```

Comment: gave point for providing exactly what was asked. Although, as Sonam Gurung pointed out this only leaves me 500 total, and I need 500 per id. Thank you it was dead on, per my question. Any idea how to make it keep 500 per id?