# MySQL delete statement based on sub-select with multiple return values while retaining 500 records for each unique value

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, limit, sql-delete

MySQL delete statement based on sub-select with multiple return values.

Here is what I am doing now:

```
DELETE FROM `dnsstats` WHERE id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = 'x.x.x.243' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
    ) foo 
)
 AND id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = 'x.x.x.40' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
  ) foo2
)
 AND id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost = 'x.x.x.50' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
  ) foo3
);
```

This works great, but I would like to select the individual IP addresses dynamically like so:

```
SELECT peerhost FROM `dnsstats` GROUP BY peerhost;
```

..and delete based on those returned values.

This is what I got from my previous question:

```
DELETE FROM `dnsstats` WHERE id NOT IN
(
 SELECT id FROM
    (
    SELECT id FROM `dnsstats` WHERE peerhost in (
            SELECT peerhost FROM `dnsstats` GROUP BY peerhost
        ) ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 500
    ) foo 
);
```

..but this leaves me with 500 total records. I would like to keep 500 records of each `peerhost`

Any idea what I can do to make this work? Thanks!

Original question: [MySQL delete statement based on sub-select with multiple return values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841562/mysql-delete-statement-based-on-sub-select-with-multiple-return-values/39841690#39841690)

Comment: Fair enough it is a different question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this using variables.  The following enumerates each `peerhost`:

```
select s.*,
       (@rn := if(@ph = peerhost, @rn + 1,
                  if(@ph := peerhost, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rn
from dnstats s cross join
     (select @ph := '', @rn := 0) params
order by peerhost, id desc;
```

You can use this in a `delete` using a subquery:

```
delete s
    from dnstats s join
         (select s.*,
                 (@rn := if(@ph = peerhost, @rn + 1,
                            if(@ph := peerhost, 1, 1)
                           )
                 ) as rn
          from dnstats s cross join
               (select @ph := '', @rn := 0) params
          order by peerhost, id desc
         ) es
         on es.id = s.id
    where rn > 500;
```

This deletes all but the first 500 rows for each `peerhost`.